# Clever way to expand 1/(z^2-n^2) in power series?

Tags: calculus, power-series

Is there a good trick to prove the following identity?

$$\frac  1 {z^2-n^2} = -\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac {z^{2i}} {n^{2(i+1)}}$$

I tried writing out the coefficients as a Taylor series, but this was pretty messy. Nevertheless, I was able to find neat formulas up to the fourth coefficient:

$$\begin{aligned} f(z):=&\frac  1 {z^2-n^2} = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac {f^{(i)}(0)} {i!}z^i \\
f(0) =& -\frac 1 {n^2}\\
f^{(1)}(z)=& -\frac z{(z^2-n^2)^2}=-z[f(z)]^2\\
f^{(2)}(z)|_{z=0}=& -[f(0)]^2 = -\frac 1 {n^4}\\
f^{(3)}(z)|_{z=0}=& -2[f(0)][f^{(1)}(0)] = 0\\
f^{(4)}(z)|_{z=0}=& -2[f(0)][f^{(2)}(0)] = -2\frac 1 {n^6}\\
\end{aligned}$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can use the expansion $$\frac{1}{1-z} = \sum _{i=0}^{\infty} z^i$$

And then by writing 
$$\frac{1}{z^2-n^2}= -\frac{1}{n^2}\frac{1}{1- \left (\frac{z}{n}\right)^2}$$
you can substitute in the first formula to get the proposed identity.